# problem calculating the inverse of a matrix

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the inverse of a square matrix of any rank N x N. I'm using a struct to store the values of the matrix which I can to effectively and I am already able to calculate the determinant. But there must be some issue with the inverse function. This is the code

```
    struct m{
        size_t row;
        size_t col;
        double *data;
    };

    void inverse(size_t n, struct m *A) /*Calculate the inverse of A */
{
    size_t i,j,i_count,j_count, count=0;
    double det = determinant(n, A);
    size_t id = 0;    
    double *d;

    struct m C; /*The Adjoint matrix */
    C.data = malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);

    C.row = n;
    C.col = n;    

    struct m *minor; /*matrices obtained by removing the i row and j column*/

    if (!(minor = malloc(n*n*(n+1)*sizeof *minor))) {
        perror ("malloc-minor");
        exit(-1);
    }    

    if (det == 0){
        printf("The matrix is singular\n");
        exit(1);
    }    

    for(id=0; id < n*n; id++){
        d = minor[id].data = malloc(sizeof(double) * (n-1) * (n-1));
        for(count=0; count < n; count++)
        {
            //Creating array of Minors
            i_count = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                j_count=0;
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if(j == count)
                        continue; // don't copy the minor column element
                    *d = A->data[i * A->col + j];
                    d++;
                    j_count++;
                }
                i_count++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(id=0; id < n*n; id++){
        for(i=0; i < n; i++){
           for(j=0; j < n; j++) 
            C.data[i * C.col + j] = determinant(n-1,&minor[id]);//Recursive call
        }
    }

    transpose(&C);
    scalar_product(1/det, &C); 
    *A = C;    
}
```

The determinant is calculated recursively with this algorithm:

```
double determinant(size_t n, struct m *A)
    {                                    
        size_t i,j,i_count,j_count, count=0;

        double det = 0;

        if(n < 1)
        {
            printf("Error\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(n==1) return A->data[0];

        else if(n==2) return (A->data[0]* A->data[1 * A->col + 1] - A->data[0 + 1] * A->data[1*A->col + 0]);    

        else{
            struct m C;

            C.row = A->row-1;
            C.col = A->col-1;

            C.data = malloc(sizeof(double) * (A->row-1) * (A->col-1));

            for(count=0; count < n; count++)
            {
                //Creating array of Minors
                i_count = 0;
                for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
                {
                    j_count=0;
                    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        if(j == count)
                            continue; // don't copy the minor column element
                        C.data[i_count * C.col + j_count] = A->data[i * A->col + j];
                        j_count++;
                    }
                    i_count++;
                }
                det += pow(-1, count) * A->data[count] * determinant(n-1,&C);//Recursive call
            }
            free(C.data);
            return det;
        }
    }
```

You can find the complete code here: https://ideone.com/gQRwVu.

Comment: What is your problem exactly??

Comment: Aside: `pow(-1, count)` is inefficient, it would be better to use an alternating variable like `sign = -sign` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use some other variable in the loop after :

```
det + =pow(-1,count) * A->data[count] *determinant (n-1,&C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of the inverse doesn't quite correspond to the algorithm described e. g. for [Inverse of a Matrix
using Minors, Cofactors and Adjugate](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-inverse-minors-cofactors-adjugate.html), even taken into account that you for now omitted the adjugate and division step. Compare your outermost `for` loop in `inverse()` to this working implementation:

```
double Rdata[(n-1)*(n-1)];              // remaining data values
struct m R = { n-1, n-1, Rdata };       // matrix structure for them
for (count = 0; count < n*n; count++)   // Create n*n Matrix of Minors
{
    int row = count/n, col = count%n;
    for (i_count = i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (i != row)                   // don't copy the current row
        {
            for (j_count = j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if (j != col)           // don't copy the current column
                    Rdata[i_count*R.col+j_count++] = A->data[i*A->col+j];
            i_count++;
        }
    // transpose by swapping row and column
    C.data[col*C.col+row] = pow(-1, row&1 ^ col&1) * determinant(n-1, &R) / det;
}
```

It yields for the given input data the correct inverse matrix

```
1  2 -4.5
0 -1  1.5
0  0  0.5
```

(already transposed and divided by the determinant of the original matrix).

Minor notes:

- The `*A = C;` at the end of `inverse()` loses the original data pointer of `*A`.
- The formatting function `f()` is wrong for negative values, since the *fraction* is also negative in this case. You could write `if (fabs(f)<.00001)`.

Comment: I don't understand the use of the bitwise '&' '^' operators here `pow(-1, row&1 ^ col&1)`

Comment: If we look at the ["checkerboard"](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/images/matrix-checkerboard.svg) on the cited page, we can see that the sign of the cells is `+` if the row and column indices are both even or both odd, and `-` if one index is even and the other one odd. `row&1`, `col&1` yield 0 if the index is even, and 1 if the index is odd; the exclusive-or `^` of them yields 1 for different, and 0 for same oddness, so we have a suitable exponent for `pow(-1, …)` to generate the needed sign.

Comment: it doesn't work in the case of a 2x2 matrix, look at this http://ideone.com/VMTSRX only 2 out of 4 coefficients are displayed correctly

Comment: @Michaelangelo Meucci - _it doesn't work_ in your case because you didn't correct the wrong _formatting function `f()`_.